# How can two Python applications hosted in different servers communicate?

Tags: python, django

I'm having an hard time figuring out how to solve a problem with a little project.

Basically i have a Django application. On the other hand i have an external Python script running. I would like to create a system where, each time a form in my Django app is submitted, the data submitted in the form is sent to the external Python application.

The external Python service should receive the data, read it, and according to who is the user and what did he submit, it should perform some tasks, then send a response.

Here is what i thought: 1) Connect the external Python app to the same database that Django is using. So that when the form is submitted, it is saved on the database and the data can be 'shared' with the second Python service. The problem with this solution is that i would need the second app to query the Database every second and perform a lot of queries, that would be a problem with performances. 2) Create an epi endpoint, so that the external python app would connect to the endpoint and fetch the data saved in the database from there. The problem is the same of the first solution. Would a service like Redis or RabbitMQ help in this case?

Importing the external Python process in my Django app is not a solution, it needs to be separate from the Django app. An important requirement for this, is speed. When new data is submitted, it needs to be received by the second Python app in the shortest time possible.

That said, i'm open to any advice or possible solution to solve this problem, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [microservices](https://microservices.io/) architecture to build this. Instead of sharing databases between two applications you have them communicate with each other through web requests. Django would shoot a request to your other app with the relevant data, and the other server would respond back with the results.

Usually one would use something like [`Flask`](http://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) (synchronous server) or [`Sanic`](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (asynchronous server) to receive/reply, but you can also look into something like [`Nameko`](https://github.com/nameko/nameko). Would also recommend looking into [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) as eventually, as you set up more of these microservices, you'll need it.

---

The idea is (i.e. using `Flask`), to create an access point that does some computation to your data and returns it back to the Django server.

***`computation.py`***

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def computation():
    data = request.get_json()
    print(data)

    return f"Hey! {data}"

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8090)
```

The Django server is simply sending a request to your server application.

***`django_mock.py`***

```py
import requests

req = requests.post('http://0.0.0.0:8090/', json={"data": "Hello"})
print(req.text)
```

The above will print out on the `computation.py` app:

```
{'data': 'Hello'}
```

and will print out on the `django_mock.py` example:

```
Hey! {'data': 'Hello'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, this is what i was thinking too. The problem here is: how do i send the requests? And the external Python app that receives the data should be in flask as well? And how does the external service receive the request

Comment: Added an example for you -- you are creating a separate server that is ran by `Flask` on some random port on your computer, and you are shooting normal web requests to it via Django.

Comment: In case the first thought that comes to head is "this architecture seems slow," I'm the first to say that I use to share that sentiment. It is, however, almost a default in today's world of large online services. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZ3wIuvmHeM) is an interesting talk about Netflix's microservice architecture if you are interested.

Comment: Well, speed is an important part in this, but what do you mean for slow? Your example is very clear and useful, i think i should follow it. Yeah, while making research for this project i bumped various times with the word 'microservice', so i think this is what i need :)

Comment: My point is that it is not as slow as it might seem at first. There are a few questions worth asking yourself before starting; an important one is: does the service need to be asynchronous or synchronous (are you receiving multiple computational requests at once, or not -- respectively)? If so, you'll need to study a bit on Python's `await` and `asyncio`, and and preferably check out [`Sanic`](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) over `Flask`. If the computation is not gonna happen in parallel to each other, you should be fine with just `Flask`.

Comment: I think it's sort of both of them. I'm a bit new to this, so i might say something stupid. But basically, if the user decides to make an instant action, the request must be instantly sent to the second application and executed by the second application. On the other hand, if the user sets an alert and decides to make this action not instantly but at a certain time LATER, the external python application will not have to execute instantly, but only at the time that the user decides.

Comment: So basically, in the second case, the user says: Do this when X happens. In this case, Django will send the record to the external application until X happens. So everytime, still in this second case, the external application will check: 'did X happen? If no i do not execute the action, if it happened i will execute'. So this is why i say it should be both synchronous and asynchronous. I know it's a bit complicated, but if you need i'm willing to explain it in chat

Comment: Both `Flask`, `Sanic` are what are called`RESTful API`. Similar to Django when you run these modules a server will spawn that is _constantly running_, and cannot be closed. What they are doing is simply waiting until an application or user shoots them a request through their endpoints. This is why I recommend looking into `Docker`, which will allow you to containerize your two separate applications and boot them up simultaneously (shameless [plug](https://medium.com/@FelipeFaria/running-a-simple-flask-application-inside-a-docker-container-b83bf3e07dd5) to an article I wrote).

Comment: Reading your article right now. Thanks for your help. i know what i need to do now :)

Comment: one last thing: how would this system change once deployed? Will this still work if i deploy the two systems on different servers? In that case, where would i send the data? I mean, i would only have to change 0.0.0.0 to the right url?

Comment: Yeah, they should work fine. You'll need to set-up where both servers are reachable by their designated IP -- the `0.0.0.0` you are talking about is [`localhost`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).

Answer (score 1):

You should build an API. The 2nd app would now be an application server and the 1st app, when it receives a form submission from the user, would persist its data to the DB and then make an API call to the 2nd app via this API. You would include key information in the API request that identifies the record in the DB.

You can use Django (e.g. DRF) or Flask to implement a simple API server in Python.

Now, this requires your app server to be up and running all the time. What if it's down? What should the 1st app do? If you need this level of flexibility, then you need to decouple these apps in some way. Either the 1st app implements some kind of backoff/retry if it can't send to the 2nd app. Or you use a reliable queueing mechanism (something like Amazon SQS).

Comment: I already thought of creating an api endpoint with DRF. So basically, someone submits the form and the data can be retrieved from the api endpoint. The problem with this is that the second Python app would have to query the endpoint for something like every second. I think that would be a bit too heavy for my first server

Comment: I'm thinking that the 2nd app would be running 24x7, but is mostly idle. The 1st app is also running 24x7 accepting form submissions. The interaction is 1st app calls API in 2nd app. 2nd app then gets relevant data from the DB. 2nd app doesn't call 1st app. Or, just have the 1st app put the relevant data into a queue and have the 2nd app poll that queue periodically.

Comment: Ok! But how would the Django app call the api in the second app?

Comment: How do you call *any* API over the web? You make an HTTP(S) GET or POST request to a known URL. From Python, you use the Requests library or equivalent. Ideally, your client authenticates, or the two systems are on a private network, so you aren't susceptible to bad actors calling your API.

Comment: Thank you! But what do you think about the approach suggested in the other answer, using Flask or a general microservice structure?

Comment: It's the same solution.

Comment: Confirming with @jarmod -- it's the same general solution on both our responses.